# CXF interceptor to preprocess incoming message

Tags: cxf

I have an operation that has an input message like this:

InputMessageType

- messageType: String
- other properties ...

I'd like to modify this messageType before it hits the target WS method and I wrote an interceptor for the Phase.USER_LOGICAL. However, in the handleMessage if I try to do:

message.getContent(InputMessageType.class) it returns null.

How could I get the reference to the InputMessageType, change it's messageType property and then let CXF call the WS with the modified input parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem as yours : message.getContent(xxx.class) returns null. I do not know why and I will check later this behaviour.

So instead I use the interceptor like this (I retrieve the MessageContentsList) :

```
public class ApiSoapActionInInterceptorService extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {

public ApiSoapActionInInterceptorService(){
    super(Phase.PRE_INVOKE);
}

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
    MessageContentsList inObjects = MessageContentsList.getContentsList(message);
    if (inObjects != null && !inObjects.isEmpty()){
        for (Iterator<Object> it = inObjects.iterator(); it.hasNext() ;){
            Object ob = it.next();
            if (ob instanceof InputMessageType){
                //TODO
            }
        }
    } else {
        //TODO 
    }
}
```

}